# Not able to run /etc/profile.d/chruby.sh while deploying using Capistrano in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, chruby

I have been trying to deploy my rails application on an EC2 instance. The steps which i have taken already are

Locally:

1. I installed all the gems by writing in `Gemfile` and `bundle install`:

   ```
   group :development do
     gem 'capistrano'
     gem 'capistrano3-puma'
     gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
     gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
     gem 'capistrano-chruby'
   end
   ```
2. I edited my `Capfile` to require the modules

   ```
   require "capistrano/setup"
   require "capistrano/deploy"
   require "capistrano/scm/git"
   install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
   require "capistrano/chruby"
   require "capistrano/bundler"
   require "capistrano/rails/assets"
   require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
   require "capistrano/puma"
   Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
   ```
3. I made the necessary changes in `config/deploy.rb` as well, specially

   ```
   set :chruby_ruby, 'ruby-2.3.0'
   ```

On the Server/Instance:

1. Installed Ruby
2. Installed Chruby and included in `/etc/profile.d/chruby.sh` these:

   ```sh
   source xx/xx/xx/chruby.sh
   source xx/xx/xx/auto.sh
   ```
3. Made a folder for app and also created `database.yml` and `application.yml`.

Having Done all this, when I run `cap production deploy`, it starts fine with checking and git cloning and linking files and directories but fails on `bundler:install`, giving an error like

```
01 /usr/local/bin/chruby-exec ruby-2.3.0 -- bundle install --path /home/deploy…
01 /bin/sh: 2: /etc/profile.d/chruby.sh:
01 source: not found
01
01 /bin/sh: 3: /etc/profile.d/chruby.sh:
01 source: not found
01
01 /bin/sh: 1:
01 chruby: not found
01
```

Since there are only examples with deploying Rails to AWS using either RVM or JRuby, I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

On surface, the problem is with '/bin/sh', which does not support 'source'.

When using 'bash', source is aliases to the '.' command. It's not clear what is the default '/bin/sh' on your system. If it's /bin/dash (Mint 19) - you will have to replace every sourec with .'

```
. xx/xx/xx/chruby.sh
. xx/xx/xx/auto.sh
```

It might be that you will have to make similar fixes to referenced files (/etc/profile.d/*.sh) which may use 'source'.

**Update 1**
Assuming the '/bin/ls' is dash (heck with `readlink -f /bin/sh`, it will show /bin/dash, or other *sh program). If using 'dash', possible to setup `alias` in /etc/profile, after checking if running under dash. In theory, will allow scripts using 'source' to work without changes.

```
case "$(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)" in
    */dash) alias source=. ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dash-o

but I have one more scenario

1. adding shebang in chruby-exec
2. `export SHELL=/bin/bash`

in [chruby-exec source on github](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/blob/master/bin/chruby-exec)

last line is

```
exec "$SHELL" "${shell_opts[@]}" -c "$command"
```

so environment variable `SHELL` plays important role here.

@alchemist95 can you please check first line of chruby-exec

you seem to have older version on chruby-exec as
[this commit **Ensure that chruby-exec runs under bash.**](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/commit/571de8cf759b73d3c0f3cac028f3f970277a379f) has been added in 2013.